# $1-\alpha$ confidence interval

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

Let $Y$ be a r.v following $N(\mu_0,1)$ for some quantile $q\in(0,1)$ and let $z_q$ denote the $q$-quantile of $N(0,1)$ normal distribution.

**Question?!**

For a $\mu_0$ would the 0.95-confidenceinteval be $$[Y-z_{(0.05)},Y-z_{(0,95)}]$$

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it so that $z_{0.95}>z_{0.05}$? If so then the interval that you mention is empty.

Comment: @drhab I think you are correct. I swapped around my intevals.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the problem, a drawing is a self evident explanation...

[image]

Of course this picture assumes you are deriving a symmetrical confidence interval, that is the optimal interval (say, the minimum size 95% confidence interval). Of course you can build many 95% confidence intervals, discarding a different error% in the two tails.

Comment: My assignment has a mistake I suppose as what I wrote is not a viable answer and it is surely correct.

Comment: I only have; [Y+z_0.99,Y+0.03], [Y-z_0.03,Y-0.99], [Y-z_0.99,Y-0.03], [Y+z_0.96,Y+0.04], and finally [Y-z_0.04,Y-0.96] for a 0.96 interval.

Comment: @user879295: the correct answer is $[Y-z_{0.99};Y-z_{0.03}]$. This because we assumed a symmetrical interval but given your possible answers this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ have standard normal distribution.

If I am well informed (I am no statistician, so please check me on it) then $P(U\leq z_q)=q$ for $q\in(0,1)$, so that: $$P(z_{0.05}<U<z_{0.95})=0.9$$

Applying that on $U=Y-\mu_0$ we find:$$P(z_{0.05}<Y-\mu_0<z_{0.95})=0.9$$or equivalently:$$P(\mu_0\in [Y-z_{0.95},Y-z_{0.05}])=0.9$$

Comment: Ah so I swapped around the errors.

Comment: @user879295 pay attention that you are looking for a 95% confidence interval thus your quantiles are $z_{0.975}$ and $z_{0.025}$

Comment: so in general; 1-(a/2) and (a/2)

Comment: @tommik What if the interval was say; 96%?

Comment: @user879295 : exactly what you wrote in your previous comment: $z_{0.98}$ and $z_{0.02}$